# Созданный в тесте пользователь при изменении в функции обработчике не сохраняется django

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

В тесте отправляю запрос на подтверждение почты, при этом специально для отладки и в тесте, и в обработчике вывожу `username` и `email_verified`.

И вот загвоздка: в обработчике после `user.save()` `email_verified = true`, а в тесте - `false`.

```
class VerifyEmailView(View):

    def get(self, request, uidb64, token):
        user = self.get_user(uidb64)
        if user and default_token_generator.check_token(user, token):
            user.is_email_verified = True
            user.save()
            print(user.username, user.is_email_verified)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('main:index')

        return render(request, 'society/invalid_token.html')`

class UserTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_user_create(self):
        # Регистрация
        url = reverse('society:registration')

        form_data = UserCreationForm(data={
            'username': 'root123',
            'password1': '123321qqwweerr',
            'password2': '123321qqwweerr',
            'email': 'roottest123@gmail.com'
        }).data

        self.client.post(url, data=form_data)
        user = User.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(user.username, 'root123')

        # Попытка авторизации без верифицированной почты
        url = reverse('society:login')

        form_data = AuthenticationForm(data={
            'username': user.username,
            'password': '123321qqwweerr'
        }).data

        self.client.post(url, data=form_data)
        self.assertEqual(user.last_login, None)

        # Верификация почты
        verify_url = reverse('society:verify_email', kwargs={
            'uidb64': urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
            'token': default_token_generator.make_token(user)
        })

        full_verify_url = f"http://127.0.0.1.8000{verify_url}"

        self.client.get(full_verify_url)
        print(user.username, user.is_email_verified)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, проблема возникает, потому что переменная `user`, которую ты печатаешь в тесте, не обновляется после изменения в обработчике `VerifyEmailView`.
Ты должен получить новую версию объекта `User` после сохранения его в обработчике подтверждения почты. Вместо использования `user` в тесте, ты можешь сделать следующее:

```py
user.refresh_from_db()
print(user.username, user.is_email_verified)
```

Это обновит `user` из базы данных и загрузит актуальные значения полей, включая `is_email_verified`.

**Тебе обьязательно нужно убедиться, что `user` в тесте синхронизирован с `user` в обработчике подтверждения почты.** Ты можешь сделать это, установив значение `user` в обработчике, равным `self.user` в тесте.

```py
class UserTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_user_create(self):

        self.client.post(url, data=form_data)
        self.user = User.objects.first()
        self.assertEqual(self.user.username, 'root123')

        self.client.get(full_verify_url)
        self.user.refresh_from_db()
        print(self.user.username, self.user.is_email_verified)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло!